# Error while Publishing WSDL

Tags: java, tomcat, wsdl

I am getting this error when i am publishing my WSDL file to TomCat6.0 using Bottom Up aproach.

IWAB0489E Error when deploying Web service to Axis runtime
  axis-admin failed with  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP (500)General error

Can any one suggest.

Comment: It looks like some error on the server side, going by the 500 response code. You might want to take a look at the Tomcat logs to get more information about the failure.

Comment: So when you are doing java2wsdl is your wsdl get generated?

Comment: @abhishek: I have WSDL already. I am working on Top Down Java Bean

Comment: @Vineet: There is nothing in the log cat

Comment: Try to create a new workspace and then generate your bean file from the wsdl,somthing might have screwed in your workspace.Before generating the bean validate your wsdl once again

Answer (score 0):

That error could mean anything. You'll need access to the logs to diagnose it. You might be looking in the wrong log file, or logging might be suppressed, or only output to the console.